# How to search for a table in beautifulsoup that independent of attribute and class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How is it possible to search for a table tag in a parsed html independent of its class and attributes ?

Comment: You can use pandas library which is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that soup below is your parsed html, then you can find any tag. Table is just a specific type of tag:

`soup.find_all('table')`

Comment: @Mahdi, you need to provide more information. Ryan has provided the appropriate solution to precisely the question you asked. If you ask a general question, you will get a general solution/answer. Simply saying, "No, it does not work" will not help you in finding a solution. What doesn't work? What error does it give you? What code are you using that generates the error so it can be reproducible? Pleas take time to read through [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)